# Bijection between $KG$-modules and $K$-representations of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, group-rings

Let $K$ be a field and $G$ be a group. Consider the group algebra $KG = \{\sum_{g}'\alpha_gu_g: \alpha _g \in K\}$ where $\{u_g: g \in G\}$ are a $K$-basis. Consider the following operations:

$$f: \{K-\mathrm{representations \ of \ G}\}\longrightarrow\{\mathrm{left\ KG-modules}\}$$
$$(V, \rho) \mapsto V$$
where $V$ has the 'scalar' multiplication $$(\sum_g \alpha_g u_g).v = \sum_g \alpha_g (\rho(g)(v))$$

$$g: \{\mathrm{left\ KG-modules}\}\longrightarrow \{K-\mathrm{representations \ of \ G}\}$$
$$M \mapsto (M, \rho)$$
where $\rho(g)v = u_g.v$ where the $.$ denotes multiplication in the $KG$-module $M$

In the book I'm reading, it is claimed that $f$ and $g$ are mutual inverses. However, I struggle to show this. In particular, I'm stuck at showing that $f \circ g$ is the identity.

**Attempt**: Start with a left $KG$-module $M$ with scalar multiplication $\cdot$

Then we can associate to this multiplication $\rho(g)(v) = u_g.v$

We want to show that the associated module structure with $(M, \rho)$ coincides with the scalar multiplication $.$, i.e. the we started with. That is, we have to show

$$(\sum_{g} \alpha_g u_g).v = \sum_{g}\alpha_g (\rho(g)v)$$

Expanding the right side, $$\sum_{g}\alpha_g (\rho(g)v)= \sum_g\alpha_g(u_g.v)$$
Expanding the left side, $$(\sum_{g} \alpha_g u_g).v= \sum_g (\alpha_g u_g).v$$
so it suffices to show $$\sum_{g} \alpha_g (u_g.v) = \sum_{g}(\alpha_g u_g).v \quad \quad (*)$$

How can I show $(*)$? Or what am I missing? Maybe I defined the scalar multiplication wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the associativity of scalar multiplication. More precisely, the scalar multiplication by $a_g$ in $V$ is, by definition, the scalar multiplication by $a_gu_e$ (where $e$ is the identity element of $G$) in $M$, so, by associativity in $M$, $a_g(u_g.v)=(a_gu_e).(u_g.v)=(a_gu_e\cdot u_g).v=(a_gu_g).v$, as desired.

Comment: It is not though since $\alpha_g(u_g .v)$ is a scalar multiplication in the vector space $V$?

Comment: @user745578: he means associativity of scalar multiplication on a module. One of the axioms defining what it means to be a module $M$ over a ring $R$ is that $r(sm) = (rs)m$ for $r, s \in R, m \in M$.

Comment: Yes, but the $K$-vector space structure on $M$ (which I assume you mean by $V$) is induced by the $KG$-module structure on $M$. It is the restriction of scalars along the natural map $K\hookrightarrow KG$, so $K$-multiplication by $a_g$ is the same as $KG$-multiplication by $a_gu_e$ ($e$ being the identity of $G$).

Comment: @Thorgott Thanks! I missed that the $K$-vector space structure was induced by the $KG$-vector space structure! It makes all sense now!

Comment: (It might be useful to edit your comment in the answer).